# How to set the range of minor ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I'm working on a bar plot. The picture I've plot as following:
[image]

To add the arrows in top and bottom axis, I set the spines color as 'none' first.

Then I plot arrow by using `axes.arrow()` function.

Finally, I reset the ticks by using `axes.set_ticks()` function.

I want to keep the minor ticks of top axis. But as what you've seen, the minor ticks in the left top corner is out of the arrow's range. How can I delete the part out of range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minor ticks can be set via [`set_minor_locator`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) using a [`FixedLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator).

An example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xlim(10**6, 1)
ax.set_xticks([10**n for n in range(-1, 5)])
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(
    [k * 10**n for n in range(-1, 5) for k in range(2, 10) if k * 10**n <= 30000]))
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]